# File upload to Linux server from Windows Desktop without providing system credentials (for server)

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, scp

I want to periodically upload data from Desktop PC to Linux server (to which I have root access). They are not on the same network (server has public static IP, client is syn up broadband) I would like folder to be uploaded to /home/userX/sync but i do not want Desktop PC to have userX credentials (as this Desktop PC should only have access to that sync folder and not full rights of userX). This is why I do not use SCP over SSH (but maybe there is a way how to do that with SCP?).

Originally I wanted to use rsync daemon on Linux server to create non system account but I quickly realised there is no encryption with rsyncd (that is a no-go as data are sensitive and transfered over internet).

How would be best way to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this for private network, i will suggest you go for `file share protocol` like `smb` or `ftp`.

I will suggest you go for `smb protocol` as you want to transfer from `window` to `linux` or vice versa, you need to install `samba server` [Check dependencies] -
You can use particular user `USERX` and set permission and provide separate password for that particular user without touching shell part of user using smbpassword command.

```
# smbpassword -a USERX
```

Comment: Hi unfortunately they are not on the same network. Server is actually in server house, desktop is in my home connected with broadband.

Comment: You can mount a remote share driver provided you have the means to provide user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Used Rsyncd over stunnel solution. Maybe there is better one but haven't found it yet.
Made rsync listen only on loopback + firewalled it (so no connections to rsyncd directly possible) and then onioned it with stunnel running as service with PSK auth.